# Applying multiple functions to a d3.js object, while entering

Tags: d3.js, dry

This might be answered in the documentation but I haven't been able to work it out.

Basically I have some standard `d3.js` code like this:

```
group.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
.enter().append('svg:rect')
  .style('fill', colour)
  .on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
    chart.currentHoverItem = d
  })
  .on('mouseout', function(d, i) {
    chart.currentHoverItem = null
 })
```

I have a few of these identical lines in different methods throughout my code. Ideally I would like to do this:

```
var addEvents() {
   this.on('mouseover', function(d, i) { ... })
   this.on('mouseout', function(d, i) { ... })
}

group.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
.enter().append('svg:rect')
  .apply(addEvents)
```

What's the nicest solution to DRY up this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for [selection.call](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-call), try this:

```
function addEvents(selection) {
    selection.on(...);
    selection.on(...);
}

group.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
.enter()
    .append('svg:rect')
    .call(addEvents);
```